# GWT Widget from HTML

Tags: html, gwt

I have a block of HTML that I would like to use as the basis of a GWT widget, but am not quite sure the best way to do so. As an example, my HTML block looks something like this:

```
<div class="my-widget">
    <div class="header">
        <span class="title">Title Text</span>
    </div>
    <div class="body">
        <span class="content">Content Text</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, I can of course paste this as a static string into an HTML widget, but in this case I need the ability to set the text of the "title" and "content" elements on the fly. This kills (or at least makes significantly more difficult) the static text option.

The first thing that comes to mind in that case is to build out the elements in GWT manually and hold references to the ones I need to alter, like so:

```
DivElement container = document.createDivElement();
setStyleName(container, "my-widget");
setElement(container);

DivElement header = document.createDivElement();
setStyleName(header, "header");
container.appendChild(header);

// Hold onto this element for later manipulation
DivElement title = document.createDivElement();
setStyleName(title, "title");
header.appendChild(title);
```

But this quickly get unmanageable for all but the simplest of layouts (which mine is not.)

What I would like is the ability to send the HTML in as static text and then do some sort of selector, like jQuery, to query the elements I want to manipulate. I'm aware of [GWT-Query](http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/) but I haven't been able to get it to run without error, and it seems to me to be a bit too early in it's lifespan for me to be comfortable integrating it into a professional product just yet.

I'm also aware of Google's [UiBinder](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/UiBinder), which sounds exactly like what I want. The problem there is, as far as I can tell, that functionality is only available in GWT 2.0, which is still in a release candidate state and therefore unusable for me.

So, given all that (sorry for the long question!) do you have any suggestions about how best to achieve something like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GWT 2.0 will be out before the end of the year. So unless you need to deliver in a few days time, I would start working with the RC2 and try out the new UIBinder approach.

Comment: Well, I need to deliver in about two weeks time. :) Cutting it kinda close for my tastes, but after playing around with GWT 2.0 last night at home for a couple hours I've come to the conclusion that any solution I come up with will fall far short of the wonderful UiBinder lib that Google has created. I'm just gonna bite the bullet on this one and start developing using that, hoping and praying that Google doesn't pull the rug out from under me when I do.

Comment: Good choice, I don't think you have to be too scared about the choice. UiBinder is an important addition and has been designed for Google Wave, so it has been used extensively. Additionally RC's are typically feature complete, they just want to make sure that there are no annoying bugs left.

Answer (score 3):

How about using HTML.wrap().  For example, if you added an id of "my-widget" to your outer-most div you could then do something like:

```
HTML myWidget = HTML.wrap(RootPanel.get("my-widget").getElement());
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand what you're getting at. I'm guessing you mean to hide an instance of the tags I want in the HTML page somewhere and duplicate them every time I need a new widget instance? That doesn't really solve to data replacement issue, and I'm fine having the markup stored as a static string in the Java code, so I don't think this actually buys me much. Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the InlineHTML widget to produce a span and control its content.

Answer (score 0):

As you probably know, GWT doesn't provide a built in widget that maps directly to a span element. If you can use a div for the title and content, then this bit of code should (no GWT on this machine, going a bit by memory) generate the DOM structure you have.

```
FlowPanel myWidget = new FlowPanel();
myWidget.setStyleName("my-widget");

SimplePanel header = new SimplePanel();
header.setStyleName("header");

Label title = new Label(titleText);
title.setStyleName("title");
header.add(title);
myWidget.add(header);

SimplePanel body = new SimplePanel();
body.setStyleName("body");

Label content = new Label(contentText);
content.setStyleName("content");
body.add(content);
myWidget.add(body);
```

From here, you can provide accessors to the content and title labels and update them as needed.

```
title.setText(newTitle);
content.setText(newContent);
```

Comment: Yes, that does indeed give me a good approximation of the HTML I posted. However, the actual HTML I'm looking to reproduce is much more complex than that and, as I said in my question, managing that many tags purely through code gets unworkable very quickly. (Especially if the layout needs any sort of updating in the future). I'm afraid this solution simply isn't feasible for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

The same as above, but getting a GWT Panel (be able to append childs). This is also useful when you need to wrapp a 3rd party toolkit GUI object as a GWT widget:

Panel gwtPanel = HTMLPanel.wrap(anElement);

Answer (score 0):

The following code suites for me:

```
HorizontalPanel divContainer = new HorizontalPanel ();
Element div = DOM.createDiv();
div.appendChild(...); // whatever element it could fit inside
divContainer.getElement().appendChild(div);
```

**Edit**

The idea behind this is manipulating the DOM with the other widgets you have already programmed.

PS: I'm using GWT 2.4